# error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required in the IPP .Net AggCat DevKit

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm trying to perform some basic actions on the .NET Sample App for Customer Account Data.
The problem happens in the following code snippet (when I'm selecting a bank and expecting its details):

```
 protected void institutions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (institutions.SelectedValue == "PleaseSelect")
                {
                    InstitutionDetails.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    InstitutionDetails.Visible = true;
                    AggregationCategorizationService svc = Services.AggCatService.GetService(Cache, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                    InstitutionDetail insutitutionDetail = svc.GetInstitutionDetails(long.Parse(institutions.SelectedItem.Value));
```

I recieve the following error:

> Error detail:  Error occurred while calling GetInstitutionDetails:
>   WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy
>   Authentication Required. Proxy-Authenticate:
>   Negotiate,Kerberos,NTLM,Basic realm="fw.solar.local" Via: 1.1 FW
>   Connection: close Proxy-Connection: close Pragma: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 701

I'm executing the sample as is, without any modifications. 
What can be the reason of it? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you test the calls using CC bank (dummy institution) details:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api

Comment: Alex, I was able to replicate your issue. I was passing the .key file in the config for private key path and got the same error as you got. Can you try the following - Go to this link and generate the .p12 file. This is your private file.   https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest   Now check your keys in API explorer first, after selecting  your .p12 file and giving the pwd. If that works, then the code should also work

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if your keys and SAML process is working fine using CAD apiexplorer
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData

Key generation using openssl - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

After generating these keys, you can create a sample app with the public key. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/009_using_customeraccountdata/0010_gettingstarted/0015_create_an_cad_integration

then use the .p12 file with pwd(if any) for SAML assertion in apiexplorer Link - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer

This code(407) is similar to 401, but indicates that the client should first authenticate with a proxy server.

Comment: Checked all these steps. The keys are fine. Besides, these keys work with Ruby sample from the same machine. What can be other reasons?

Comment: Can I recieve OAuth Access Token and OAuth Access Token Secret from the SDK? I suppose that the reason in the OAuth procedure.

Comment: I checked all the parameters in the web.config. They are 100% correct (I checked them with the ones in apiexplorer https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CUSTOMERACCOUNTDATA).